# Rails 4 Cannot access hash in nested form (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, nested-forms, parameters

I've build quite complex form which creates one prescription with many realtions. I am using this syntax in view:

```
- provide(:title, 'Create prescription')
%h1 Add medicines to prescription
.row
  .span6.offset3
    = form_for @prescription do |f|
      = render 'shared/error_prescription_messages'
      %p
        = f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value => params[:patient_id]
        = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
      = f.fields_for :relations do |builder|
        = render 'child_form', :f => builder
      %p= f.submit "Submit"
```

chlid_form is quite simple :

```
- it=f.options[:child_index].to_i
- n= it.to_s

%h2
  = "Medicine ##{it+1}"

= f.hidden_field :medicine_id, :id => "my_medicine_id#{it}"
- if params[:prescription].nil? || params[:prescription][:relations_attributes][n.to_sym][:medicine_name].nil?
  = f.autocomplete_field :medicine_name, autocomplete_medicine_name_relations_path, :id_element => "#my_medicine_id#{it}"
- else
  = f.autocomplete_field :medicine_name, autocomplete_medicine_name_relations_path, :id_element => "#my_medicine_id#{it}", :value => params[:prescription][:relations_attributes][n.to_sym][:medicine_name]

= f.label :amount, "Amount of medicine boxes"
= f.number_field :amount, :value => 1

= f.label :daily
= f.number_field :daily, :value => 1

= f.label :period_in_days, "Duration of treatment (in days)"
= f.number_field :period_in_days, :value => 1
```

So as you can see I'm using `f.options[:child_index]` to get index of child (0,1,2...) cause I generate multiple items with this particular form. I then put it to variable `it` and sucessfully use it in `:id_element => "#my_medicine_id#{it}"` which works PERFECTLY fine (creates my_medicine_id0, my_medicine_id1 ....) Although it doesn't work in this line:

`:value => params[:prescription][:relations_attributes][n.to_sym][:medicine_name]`

where `n` is just `n=it.to_s`.

I though somethings wrong in controller but if I change this line to whatever 
`:value => params[:prescription][:relations_attributes]**[:'0']**[:medicine_name]` or any other integer from 0 to 4 everything works great, but I NEED dynamic change in this one. So I got proof that it DOES work because it generates integer fine here `"#my_medicine_id#{it}"` but won't work in hash! And when I print the whole hash from params I get this:

`{"patient_id"=>"7", "user_id"=>"1", "relations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"medicine_id"=>"13490", "medicine_name"=>"Locacid 500 mcg/g (0,05%) (1 tuba 30 g)", "amount"=>"0", "daily"=>"1", "period_in_days"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"medicine_id"=>"", "medicine_name"=>"", "amount"=>"1", "daily"=>"1", "period_in_days"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"medicine_id"=>"", "medicine_name"=>"", "amount"=>"1", "daily"=>"1", "period_in_days"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"medicine_id"=>"", "medicine_name"=>"", "amount"=>"1", "daily"=>"1", "period_in_days"=>"1"}, "4"=>{"medicine_id"=>"", "medicine_name"=>"", "amount"=>"1", "daily"=>"1", "period_in_days"=>"1"}}}`

so to get the values I need it's pretty obvious that
`params[:prescription][:relations_attributes][SOME_KIND_OF_INETEGER][:medicine_name]` should work, but doesn't.

Controller code:

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user
before_action :doctor_user,     only: [:new, :create]
before_action :pharmacist_user, only: [:update]

def new
    @prescription =Prescription.new
    5.times { @prescription.relations.build }
end

def create
    @prescription = Prescription.new(new_prescription_params)
    if @prescription.save
        flash[:success] = "Prescription created."
        redirect_to @prescription
else
  5.times { @prescription.relations.build }
        render 'new', :prescription => params[:prescription]
    end
end

def show
    @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id])
    @medicines = @prescription.medicines.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end

def update
    @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id])
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])

    if !prescription_expired?(@prescription)
        @prescription.realized = 1
        if @prescription.save
            flash[:success] = "Prescription realized."
            redirect_to @patient
        else
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    else
            flash[:notice] = "Can't realize, prescription expired."
            redirect_to @patient
     end
end

private

    def new_prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).
        permit(:patient_id, :user_id, relations_attributes: [:medicine_id, :medicine_name, :amount, :daily, :period_in_days])
    end 

    def doctor_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.function == "doctor"
    end

    def pharmacist_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.function == "pharmacist"
    end

    def prescription_expired?(presc)
        presc.created_at < 1.month.ago
    end

    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
            store_location
            flash[:notice] = "Please log in."
            redirect_to login_url
        end
    end
```

end

I run out of ideas so I ask you guys if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to by rails way of doing this. Why do you bind a form elements with model and then override this attribute values? This should be done in the controller. Please update your question with controller code so we'll clean it up.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing `[n.to_sym]` ... I would think `[n]` would work, no? It's not a symbol in the hash dump.

Comment: Don't write anything personal. It is frustrating to read someone claiming that they are frustrated. That has nothing to do with the question. And often, beginners write words like "weird/strange behavior", but in most cases, there is nothing weird or strange about the language/framework, and is most likely it is the thinking by those people who claim that is strange.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn [n] doesn't work, I tried many variations like :"#{n}" and loads of different stuff.

Comment: @BroiSatse I added controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in using `params` in your view since you already assigned those to your models. Also when you rendering your new action, those params doesn't exist as nothing has been send to the server yet. Just get rid of all the `values` from inputs.

Your partial should look like:

```
- it=f.options[:child_index].to_i
- n= it.to_s

%h2
  = "Medicine ##{it+1}"

= f.hidden_field :medicine_id, :id => "my_medicine_id#{it}"
= f.autocomplete_field :medicine_name, autocomplete_medicine_name_relations_path

= f.label :amount, "Amount of medicine boxes"
= f.number_field :amount

= f.label :daily
= f.number_field :daily

= f.label :period_in_days, "Duration of treatment (in days)"
= f.number_field :period_in_days
```

If you want your fields to have default value, set default value inside your database.

Comment: @Herwish - Defaulting values is definitively a model thing, not the controller and definitively not the view. TBH, I've never found any use of value param. As I've mentioned at the bottem of the answer, set a default value on database column or add `after_initialize` hook to your model.

Comment: Instead of `@prescription = Prescription.new` do `@prescription = patient.find(parms[:patient_id]).prescriptions.build`

Comment: @Herwish - get rid of `values` there as well. Do `@prescription = patient.find(parms[:patient_id]).prescriptions.build(user_id: current_user)`

Comment: Yes, your solution works great.
Probably i will need to refactor my code in the rest of the application cause I bet I used bad kind of solution in few places.
Anyways this is my first project in RoR and I still got a lot to learn so thanks for your patience @BroiSatse

Comment: can you have a quick look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896389/rails-4-custom-validation-with-many-to-many-relationship ?