# Rails 4 custom validation with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I've got app with model where prescriptions are connected with medicines via relations table.
I use one form to create one prescription with 5 relations which contains information about medicine_id, amount, daily and so on. However, medicine table has got a lot more information and thats what I would like to use when validating.

For example - I want to check if field `dose` from table `medicines` is like `'%pills'. If so, I would like to do some calculation to check if an amount that user put during filling the form is in range (lets say 30-40 is only correct for this specific medicine)

My relation model:

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :prescription
  belongs_to :medicine

  validates :amount, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }
  validates :daily, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }
  validates :period_in_days, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }

  validate :amount_limit, :if => :pills_form?

  private

    def amount_limit

    end

    def pills_form

    end
end
```

How can I get these informations that are in the medicine table when Im validating relations? Or is there any other, more proper way of doing this?

Comment: You should be able to get these information simply by calling `medicine.dose`

Comment: @BroiSatse i am impressed with how nicely it works, you were right of course. Now its the case of getting rid of the prefixes in errors that rails puts before my error message. example `errors.add(:amount, "An amount of medicine cannot exceed 90 days of treatment.")` and because I validate prescription not relation final error looks like `Relations amount An amount of medicine cannot exceed 90 days of planned treatment.`. It happens with any field from nested form which is relations. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Aswer thanks to the @BroiSatse

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prescription
  belongs_to :medicine

  validates :amount, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }
  validates :daily, numericality: {only_integer: true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1 }

  validate :amount_limit, :if => :pills_form?

  private

    def amount_limit
      max_amount = self.daily * 90
      in_box_amount = medicine.cardinality.scan(/\d+/).first
      sum = self.amount * in_box_amount.to_i
      if sum > max_amount
        errors.add(:amount, "An amount of medicine cannot exceed 90 days of treatment.")
      end
    end

    def pills_form?
      pill_form_array = ['plaster' , 'globul', 'czop', 'guma', 'tablet', 'pastyl', 'kaps', 'lamel']
      pill_form_array.any? { |item| medicine.form =~ /#{item}/ }
    end
end
```